# Displaying selections from a Dropdown Check List

Tags: interaction-design, usability, lists, input-fields

First of all, I apologize for my Englsih and will try to be as clear as possible!

I'm currently having a problem with a Dropdown Check List.

I have, on the left of the search results, a Dropdown Check List which manages the different categories (38) displayed. When selected, a category appears in plain text in a field. When the user selects all 38 categories,  they appear in plain text but in line and separated with a comma which makes it unclear and very hard to read.

I do not wish to cut the plain text list in the field because the categories are home-made and users are not necessarily familiar with them.

It's also way easier for me to see what has been checked or unchecked in a search.
With a short list, the user has to click to display the plain list and know what was checked.

I tried with Harvest's multiple select chosen but the result is the same (too long).

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Could you please add a wireframe or screenshot to make it clear?

Comment: I think the question is that do you really need a Dropdown checklist?

Comment: sorry roland i coudl not upload an image because i am too "young" in this chat;-) No i don't really need a dropdown check-list. i think, i need something to display elements in a left search menu. the tool must manage a huge list.

Comment: If the content is important and requires multiple selection, why not use a regular list? (that does not collapse into one row)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your English is really not that bad.

[image]

It sounds like Harvest's free selector library may be to your benefit. http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

These work much like Facebook's name tagging when composing a message. While it's difficult to say from your description, it sounds like you have two interfaces where only one is needed.

Either that, or a feature like that of the previous link would basically integrate those two interactive elements into a single element.

This may also solve your dilemma because each item in the text box is trivially a comma separated element, but can still be treated like an object. The plugin also updates the dropdown list removing items that have already been selected.

**Update**

My team has moved to Select2, it's a well-maintained fork of Chosen with more features.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this solution could work for you: (I have seen this structure for Tagging, but could work also for you). Even a search/filter field could be added to the left side panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the use-cases for selection are clustered at the edges, meaning that almost all selections will either be a few categories selected or all categories selected except a few. If this is true, then I would approach the problem like this:

- customize the text shown to the user when the dropdown is not dropped down.
- if only a few are selected, show the selected categories, e,g. "Category 1, Category 2"
- if all are selected, don't list each category. Instead, show text indicating all are selected, e.g. "(all)"
- if almost all are selected, except a few, then show text indicating which ones are *not* selected, e.g. "(all) except Category, Category 2"
- if there are lots of categories selected, but not so many that almost all are selected, then show the first few categories and then a "summary" item, e.g. "Category 1, Category 2, Category 3, and 18 more".
- make sure there's a tooltip so users who hover over the dropdown checklistbox will see the full list.